# Joining fields correctly alligned from two tables SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok. It's my first day with SQL. I'm not being lazy I have searched and searched...

I am simply trying to export data to be used to make address labels. I wrote the query:

```
SELECT name, cb_direccin, cb_poblacin, cb_cdigopostal, cb_provincia
FROM jos_users, jos_comprofiler
```

But the problem is it puts the same name from (the first one) the table `jos_users` in front of all the addresses. I need the name which corresponds to the address (they have the same `id` number) in front of it.

I have tried to learn all about SQL (join, unify etc) and would rather understand it and solve it myself, but I'm stuck. Sorry. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use proper `JOIN` syntax. What you have now is the cartesian product of all records of both tables since you did not specify their linking columns.

```
SELECT  name, cb_direccin, cb_poblacin, cb_cdigopostal, cb_provincia
FROM    jos_users a 
        INNER JOIN jos_comprofiler b
           ON a.ID = b.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you that's it! And even better, I understand it. I had been playing with inner join but didn't know the syntax (even though I read dozens of articles on syntax, it's hard when you don't recognize all the terms). Thanks again!!!